# Ranging date equal to today date

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

asking about Date function in php
I want to make a date range in a week (monday-saturday) that the date follow equal to today date in a dropdown option. Let say today 16 Aug then the range will be start in 15 Aug - 20 Aug, 22 Aug - 27, 29 Aug - 3 Sept, and so on.

I use this syntax

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="'.date("Ymd", strtotime("$i weeks monday")).'">'.date("d F", strtotime("$i weeks monday"))." - ".date("d F", strtotime("$i weeks saturday")).'</option>';
    }
  }
?>
```

It works perfect only in Monday, but the next day when I open the web, it shows next week monday for all option. It seems that when monday passed, that monday is out of the list in this week and next monday become this weeks monday. It is a bug with strtotime or there is a better strtotime syntax to use ? If possible, I want to avoid using if to check date, but if is not, then are there any possible simple syntax to use in strtotime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to do with `strtotime()` and doubly so as a one-liner. Using [`DateTime()` and it's related classes](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) gets this to be straightforward, though.

```
$start    = new DateTimeImmutable('Monday this week');
$end      = $start->add(new DateInterval('P8W'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $week) {
    $monday   = $week->format('Ymd');
    $saturday = $week->modify('next Saturday')->format('Ymd');

    printf('<option value="%s">%s - %s</option>', $monday, $monday, $saturday);
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/623481)

What happens here is:

1. Use [`DateTimeImmutable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) to create our start date which is the Monday of the current week
2. Set our end date to be 8 weeks from now (using [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php))
3. Set the interval for our loop to be one week time periods
4. Put it all into a [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object that we can iterate through
5. Get the format for our Monday date
6. Get the format for our Saturday date
7. Echo it out in an `<option>` tag (using [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) so it is more readable in our code)

Comment: what is P1w/ P8W means in Interval ? Never use DateTimeImmutable() before

Comment: `P1W~ means "Period 1 Week". From there you can guess what `P8W`  means. :) `DateTimeImmutable()` is exactly like `DateTime()` but always returns a new object insteads of modifying the original one. Depending on what you're doing it may not matter which one you use.

Comment: I tried and it works, Thank man. hope it not broken if the day change.

When I use, strtotime('Monday this week'), the result like I describe before in question.
But when in your code, it works even the line is exactly the same ? Do you know about this ?

Comment: `strtotime()` does not handle date manipulation as well as DateTime does. It's good for basic things but once you start to get more advanced it starts to break down.